# Which OLED to get - Sony or LG?

Tags: monitors

TLDR; Is the 2021 Bravia A90J better than 2022 LG C2 in HDR10 ?

Requirements:

- OLED
- 120 Hz
- 4k
- HDR10
- 48"+ , but ideally 55" as I use it also for C++/DirectX11 coding, plus playing XBOX One X

Best Buy just (2 hrs ago) dropped a deal on Bravia A90J - that's the 55" OLED (120 Hz@4k@HDR10). It's now $1000 (instead of $1,400).
I was dead set on getting LG C2, however yesterday I saw C3 in person in Best Buy (it just got installed yesterday in my local BestBuy) and I can't believe what I read in the  reviews that I read so far (on C3) saying that C3 is "marginally better in HDR10".

In person, the 55" C3 (2023 model) has an insane contrast, really bright highlights, yet deeper blacks. It was sitting right above 55" C2 (2022 model). I was blown away. Very, very far from "marginal upgrade"...

But, the Bravia A90J is a 2021 model. I don't know what kind of (if any) updates the Bravia got (other than firmware and maybe some filters/SW/etc.), but then again, the panel is 2021, so while it might have had some advantages in HDR 2 yrs ago, I seriously doubt it can remotely compete with the C2, let alone C3, right ?

HDR10 is important to me, because I am updating my 3D engine to HDR10, so I would ideally develop and test it on best available OLED screen (within reason - financially, of course). Except I don't want to shell out $1,900 for the 55" LG C3. That just sounds ridiculous. Which is where the $999 deal comes in.

Is the 2021 Bravia A90J better than 2022 LG C2 in HDR10 ?

The things are further complicated, because C3 is now available in 42" ($1,250) and 48" sizes. Meaning I still get the C3 panel with its (it's just smaller, but given that I sit few feet from it, not a big deal).
And I can't seem to justify saving $250 to get a 2021 panel (not after seeing C3 yesterday in person).

Note that I don't care for image quality of the panel for movies. I either play games (hence 120 Hz@4k) or do coding on this TV. So, even if LG had a really ****** Movie image quality, it would be, basically, irrelevant, as I wouldn't besmirch it with movies...